# VECTORSZ size is too small in ispin

Tags: formal-languages, formal-verification, model-checking, spin, formal-methods

i do not know where to write such types of commands in ispin
like -DVECTORSZ and many more

so anyone can tell where these commands are written and recompile.they said -DVECTORSZ=N and N>1024.I KNOW WHAT IS COMMAND TO WRITE THIS WHERE TO WRITE IN ISPIN I DONOT KNOW THIS